# node-postgres how to escape parameters?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I know about [parameterized query](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query), but since I have to programmatically construct the *where condition*, taking count of the parameters and building the parameters array is a task much more complex than simply calling an *escape* function when required. So:

**is there a parameters escape function in node-postgres?**

Comment: Constructing a values array dynamically isn't that hard. Or consider using an ORM that does this for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, since [this PR](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/396) there are [`client.escapeIdentifier`](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/684cd09bcecbf5ad5f451fdf608a3e9a9444524e/packages/pg/lib/client.js#L443-L446) and [`client.escapeLiteral`](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/684cd09bcecbf5ad5f451fdf608a3e9a9444524e/packages/pg/lib/client.js#L448-L463) <s>(sadly [still undocumented](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1978))</s>, and since [PR2954 (released with v8.11.0)](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/2954) they are exported and documented as [`pg.escapeIdentifier`](https://node-postgres.com/apis/utilities#pgescapeidentifier) and [`pg.escapeLiteral`](https://node-postgres.com/apis/utilities#pgescapeliteral).

However, it is not recommended to use them when you can use parameterised queries, and for dynamic `WHERE` condition you can easily construct a query object with `text` and `values` on the fly.

Comment: `client.escapeLiteral` is the answer I was looking for; the fact it is undocumented makes clear why I wasn't able to find it. Thank you.