# Parametrized raw SQL queries on Prisma with IN are causing `Invalid `prisma.queryRaw()`

Tags: postgresql, prisma, prepared-statement

I have the below resolver using `prisma` with raw SQL queries.

```
const getWarmTransferStatusReport: QueryResolvers['getWarmTransferStatusReport'] = async (
  parent,
  { input },
  context: Context
): Promise<WarmTransferStatusLog[]> => {
  // pageNumber starts from 0, pageSize is an integer > 0 (natural number)
  const { pageSize, pageNumber, sortColumn, sortDirection, userEmail, status } = input;

  const parametrizedArgs = [];
  let rawSqlSubQuery = `  SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY $1 $2),
      *,
      DATE_PART('day', (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamp - created_at::timestamp) AS time_days,
      DATE_PART('hour', (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamp - created_at::timestamp) AS time_hours,
      DATE_PART('minute', (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamp - created_at::timestamp) AS time_minutes,
      DATE_PART('second', (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamp - created_at::timestamp) AS time_seconds
    FROM
      "public"."Warm_Transfer_Status_Log" 
    WHERE
      time_in_status_seconds IS NULL`;

  parametrizedArgs.push(sortColumn, sortDirection);

  if (status) {
    parametrizedArgs.push(status);
    rawSqlSubQuery += ` AND warm_transfer_status_id IN ($${parametrizedArgs.length})`;
  }
  if (userEmail) {
    parametrizedArgs.push(userEmail);
    rawSqlSubQuery += ` AND user_email IN ($${parametrizedArgs.length})`;
  }
  const rawSqlQuery = `
    SELECT 
      sub.*,
      CONCAT(TO_CHAR(sub.time_days, 'fm00'), ':', TO_CHAR(sub.time_hours, 'fm00'), ':', TO_CHAR(sub.time_minutes, 'fm00'), ':', TO_CHAR(cast(sub.time_seconds as int), 'fm00')) AS time_in_status
    FROM (
      ${rawSqlSubQuery}
    ) AS sub
    WHERE
      row_number > $${parametrizedArgs.length + 1} AND row_number <= $${parametrizedArgs.length + 2}
    ORDER BY
      $1 $2;
  `;
  parametrizedArgs.push(pageNumber * pageSize, (pageNumber + 1) * pageSize));

  console.log('rawSqlQuery:', rawSqlQuery);

  return context.prisma.$queryRaw(rawSqlQuery, parametrizedArgs);
};
```

When I run this, it errs with:

```
Raw query failed. Code: `42601`. Message: `db error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"`.
```

My guess that the problem is related to `IN ()` check, maybe. Prisma has a special helper - `Prisma.join`, which maybe needs to be used.

Could I parametrized queries with Prisma raw SQL? I understood the documentation that this should work. What is the correct way of doing it?

I want my final query, after parameter substitution, to be:

```
SELECT 
  sub.*,
  CONCAT(TO_CHAR(sub.time_days, 'fm00'), ':', TO_CHAR(sub.time_hours, 'fm00'), ':', TO_CHAR(sub.time_minutes, 'fm00'), ':', TO_CHAR(cast(sub.time_seconds as int), 'fm00')) AS time_in_status
FROM (
    SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY user_email asc),
  *,
  DATE_PART('day', (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamp - created_at::timestamp) AS time_days,
  DATE_PART('hour', (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamp - created_at::timestamp) AS time_hours,
  DATE_PART('minute', (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamp - created_at::timestamp) AS time_minutes,
  DATE_PART('second', (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamp - created_at::timestamp) AS time_seconds
FROM
  "public"."Warm_Transfer_Status_Log" 
WHERE
  time_in_status_seconds IS NULL AND warm_transfer_status_id in ('BREAK', 'WARM_TRANSFER') AND user_email in ('owltestsla1@domain.com', 'shaf@domain.com')
) AS sub
WHERE
  row_number > 0 AND row_number < 26
ORDER BY
  user_email asc;
```

Comment: What are the types of `pageSize, pageNumber, sortColumn, sortDirection, userEmail, status`?

Comment: Did you mean to use [`$queryRawUnsafe`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryrawunsafe)? The `$queryRaw` method seems to be documented with a different interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `IN` expression is fine<sup>1</sup>. The problem is rather with `ORDER BY $1 $2`, which isn't valid SQL. Parameterised statements do take *values* for parameters, as if you would put a value *literal* expression in the query at that position. Your query "expands" to `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 'user_email' 'asc')`, which are just two constant strings. You cannot parameterise a query by keywords and identifiers such as column names. For this, you would need to use string interpolation with [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70556668/1048572):

```
if (!['asc', 'desc'].includes(sortDirection)) throw new Error('invalid sortDirection');
if (!['user_email', …].includes(sortColumn)) throw new Error('invalid sortColumn');
let rawSqlSubQuery = `
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ${ escapeIdentifier(sortColumn) } ${ sortDirection }),
    …
`;
```

<sub>1: Syntactically. But `IN` does not work with arrays passed as parameters. It seems you don't want `IN` but rather `= ANY $2::text[]`.</sub>