# What is the correct syntax for dollar-parameters in PostgreSQL queries?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, parameters, sql-injection, node-postgres

I am struggling with the correct syntax for a dollar-parameter. It sometimes works, sometimes not.

I am using the 'pg' package for NodeJS, but since AFAIK parsing the query happens on the server side, I don't expect this to matter.

Code:

```js
const client: PoolClient = ...;
await client.query('SELECT \'foo\' = $1', [projectId]);
await client.query('SET "gvc.currentProjectId" = $1', [projectId]);
```

The first query is obviously useless, but I added it to experiment with the syntax. An error occurs in the second query, so the first one seems to work. The second one fails with:

```
unexpected exception error: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

Is it even possible to use dollar-parameters in the value for SET? I want to secure my application against SQL injection attacks, so manually escaping the projectId is a last resort.

Comment: As for "manually escaping", see https://stackoverflow.com/q/70556273/1048572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/333947, SET can indeed only take literal values, no parameters or query results. That post links to the set_config command, which does not have such a restriction.

```
https://pgpedia.info/s/set_config.html
```

Neither the post not the documentation explain why both exist, nor why SET cannot take parameters since set_config demonstrates that it is possible to do so.

Simply using set_config over SET solves the problem.

Comment: This is not about `SET` taking parameters, it is about `pg` failing to do the substitution in `query('SET "gvc.currentProjectId" = $1', [projectId])` and passing `$1` to the database directly. Best guess `pg` does not recognize `SET` as a command it can use parameters with.

Comment: The linked post suggests that this is a general restriction of the SET command, not related to the pg package. What you wrote is interesting because it suggests that parameters must be supported per-command by the database client -- I thought that the client just sends the command including any dollar-sequences as plain text, and the argument values separately, and finding the parameters in the query happens completely server-side. Can you give any sources to learn more about that?

Comment: Yeah that must be it. My experience with this is using Python and `psycopg2`, there it works as the parameters are bound client side. When I use `psycopg(3)` which binds server side I get the same error. The source for `pg` is here [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/tree/master). I did a quick poke around and could not find the relevant part.